# Is there code folding for gedit?

Tags: gedit

Does anyone know about a way to get code folding in gedit? I've found [this plugin](http://code.google.com/p/gedit-folding/source/checkout) in google code, but looks like dead and doesn't work with the latest gedit.

Comment: I think this question is slightly different and in its core not covered in the other question.

Comment: @Murat: Even if it is, it's better to have one question per question.

Comment: The question referenced in the first comment simply asks for a code-folding feature, with the currently leading answer stating there is a problem with the plugin, but not proposing a solution. This question is intended to find that solution, so is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Code folding in a good manner is stated to be difficult because the GtkSourceView component would need to be edited.

Still there was this  simple plugin that used to work until gedit 2.28...

And it's on the [official roadmap](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/RoadMap) at least...

To answer your question: No currently no option (unless someone would fix the old plugin)

Comment: Someone needs to look at this plugin (https://github.com/mikecrittenden/gedit-folding) and use it as a starting point for an official code-folding plugin for Gedit 3.

Answer (score 6):

Solution in this page works:

https://github.com/mikecrittenden/gedit-folding

Comment: +1, it is very basic (keyboard based only), but works! (tested on v2.30.4)

Comment: This plugin needs to be updated for Gedit 3... Ad used as a starting point for an official code folding plugin for Gedit.

Comment: @trusktr -- looks like there are a few forks for Gedit 3. Here is one: https://github.com/aeischeid/gedit-folding

Comment: @mason81 Thanks! I've since moved on to Vim though (and probably NeoVIm soon). :D

Answer (score 4):

[gedit-folding](https://github.com/JacekPliszka/gedit-folding) by Jacek Pliszka is a nice simple tool to fold code on multiple levels. It is featured on the [GNOME Wiki page for third party plugins for gedit 3.14](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/ThirdPartyPlugins_v3.14).

Comment: Just for completeness: Jacek Pliszka is the currently [most active contributor](https://github.com/dstarod/gedit-folding/network), not the original author.

Answer (score 0):

[This solution](https://github.com/aeischeid/gedit-folding) was recommended on a [duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160301/code-folding-plug-in-for-gedit-3-2-1).

It took 919 lines of bash code and folded onto one page. It helps me spot constants I need to move into functions. It also made me realize some functions need to be broken down into smaller chunks:

[image: gedit folding.png]

**Note:** To install it I had to first create the directory

```
/home/myname/.local/share/gedit/plugins
```

Then change to that directory and run

```
git clone https://github.com/aeischeid/gedit-folding
```

Next use gedit's menu `Edit` -> `Preferences` -> `Plugins` -> `Folding`

I only wish I new Python (it's only 174 line program) so I could modify it to save folded code marks and reapply them when file is reopened. I can see now I'll be keeping the same file open for 2 weeks :)

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 22.04. It is not super nice however.