# Code folding plug-in for gedit 3.2.1?

Tags: gnome, gedit

I need the code folding property in gedit, and I found online a folding.gedit-plugin online, but it never works.  My gedit is of version 3.2.1, and it is said that the plugin folding.gedit-plugin was made for 2.x version only.

So is there a code folding plugin for gedit of version 3.2.1?  Thanks!

Comment: Interested too. Anyone has an answer to this problem? I need the same for version 3.2.3.

Comment: @Elysium - I dont have access to v3.2.3 - but does the code-folding plugin here work for you? https://github.com/gmate/gmate

Comment: Is there a particular language you are looking to format?

Comment: **Close Voters** This question is 7 years old, the duplicate referenced is 9 years old and the answers that work today (posted to both questions) were released 4 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

It is here, along with the installation guide.

```
https://github.com/aeischeid/gedit-folding
```

For me, it works on gEdit 3.18.3, and may works on later version.

Comment: Hmm it appears this was released 4 years ago? Nifty little 174 line python program. Note you have re-collapse code every time you open the file. It doesn't remember lines folded and repeat the steps for you when file is reopened.

Answer (score 0):

according to this question: [Is there code folding for gedit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8384/is-there-code-folding-for-gedit) , it seems difficult to have code folding in gedit 3.x but there's one option that does the job (see answers from the link above).

As an alternative, I would suggest you to install `geany` which is a simple and lightweight text/code editor in ubuntu repos ( `sudo apt-get install geany`) and you can enable code folding by simply going to  `edit>preferences>editor` and checking "code folding". You can also remove any extra panes (side or bottom panes) to make it feel as simple as it is gedit.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, What about VIM editor? It's the best editor I've used ever. It works with lot of code, JAVA, Perl, html, css, C, C++, Python, LaTex... etc lot of them. work fine.

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```