# Is there a text editor for html files that actually breaks down the content of the file into openable columns?

Tags: text-processing

I am wondering if there is a file editor for Ubuntu that can open and close the different parts of the html file as in the screenshot below:

[image]

"menu a" here has a little icon that I can click and the whole thing would be folded in and that way I can see the different parts of the file better. Or can gedit do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Geany](http://www.geany.org/Main/HomePage)

I find it good and quite user-friendly.

Comment: Thanks a lot To Do. I'll give it a go, but I am an old-fashioned guy and since I have been using gedit for a while...well, I'd rather stick to it.

Comment: Actually Geany is similar to Gedit but more powerful. I think it's worth giving it a try.

Comment: I have just installed it and I guess I am gonna use it. It is pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

You need a plugin for Gedit for this to work and you can find one [here](http://code.google.com/p/gedit-folding/downloads/list). But I used that 2 years ago for the last time and we did switch to Gedit 3 after this plugin was introduced. Might not work(...). No answer here: [Code folding plug-in for gedit 3.2.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160301/code-folding-plug-in-for-gedit-3-2-1) so it is not widely used or not working.

I myself have made the switch over to Aptana. It has folding for CSS and HTML and alot more. Any other coding style based editor will have folding incorporated.  Some I used and know about: Eclipse and Kate (Kate is K so does not integrate as well).

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. I think I'll stick to gedit, but I have no clue what to do with these py and plugin files. I am a bit of a newbie here, but would like to learn.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61785/how-do-i-install-a-plugin-for-gedit-v3  ;)

Comment: ok, it just turns out to be a waste of time. This wont work with version 3+...thanks anyway Rinz.